# Spring MVC+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9o-0N7tMg8&list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh&index=19 to create a website in Spring MVC. The tutorial uses HSQL database, but i preferred to use MySql. I was able to fetch the data from database, however i am unable to save user data in Database.

My configurations are:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.coolbreeze.realestate
<context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
```

```
<!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

hibernate-context.xml :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="url" value="${app.jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${app.jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
 p:packagesToScan="com.coolbreeze.realestate">
 </bean>
 <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="emf"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.coolbreeze.realestate.entity" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="persistenceProvider">
<bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
</property>
</bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.coolbreeze.realestate.repository" 
entity-manager-factory-ref = "emf" transaction-manager-ref = "transactionManager" />
```

hibernate-cfg.xml :

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
 <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
 <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
  Existing data will be deleted! -->
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

UserController :

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@ModelAttribute("user")
public User construct(){
    return new User();
}
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doRegister(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    userService.save(user);
    return "register";
}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public void save(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Please Help me, I am also not able to see the sql queries in console, however it is configured to show in hibernate configuration xml.

Really Appreciate you Help.

Thank You

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are reason you have a SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory defined? If you cannot see log output out then try taking the contents in the file detailed here: http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/ and pasting it to a new file named log4j.properties. If you are using maven then create this under src/main/resources

Comment: any exception stacktrace you got in console?

Answer (score 0):

where are you implementing the DB save method for UserRepository?

Here is a very well documented tutorial on the same - http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial